# How to build lua 5.3 with library "lfs"?

Tags: c++, makefile, lua, lua-5.3

In my project, I build Lua5.1 with library "lfs"(https://github.com/keplerproject/luafilesystem) by adding lfs.c and lfs.h in Makefile of Lua, it works well.

But after upgrading to lua5.3, it fails like this:

```
$ lua test.lua
lua: test.lua:1: module 'lfs' not found:
no field package.preload['lfs']
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/lfs.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/lfs/init.lua'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/lfs.lua'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/lfs/init.lua'
no file './lfs.lua'
no file './lfs/init.lua'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/lfs.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/loadall.so'
no file './lfs.so'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    test.lua:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

test.lua:

```
local lfs = require"lfs"
function attrdir (path)
    for file in lfs.dir(path) do
        if file ~= "." and file ~= ".." then
            local f = path..'/'..file
            print ("\t "..f)
            local attr = lfs.attributes (f)
            assert (type(attr) == "table")
            if attr.mode == "directory" then
                attrdir (f)
            else
                for name, value in pairs(attr) do
                    print (name, value)
                end
            end
        end
    end
end

attrdir(".")
```

I've checked that the latest "lfs" library is Lua5.3 supported.

My OS is macos 10.12, and here is the makefile i'm using

```
# Makefile for building Lua
# See ../doc/readme.html for installation and customization instructions.

# == CHANGE THE SETTINGS BELOW TO SUIT YOUR ENVIRONMENT =======================

# Your platform. See PLATS for possible values.
PLAT= none

CC= gcc -std=gnu99
CFLAGS= -O2 -Wall -Wextra -DLUA_COMPAT_5_2 $(SYSCFLAGS) $(MYCFLAGS)
LDFLAGS= $(SYSLDFLAGS) $(MYLDFLAGS)
LIBS= -lm $(SYSLIBS) $(MYLIBS)

AR= ar rcu
RANLIB= ranlib
RM= rm -f

SYSCFLAGS=
SYSLDFLAGS=
SYSLIBS=

MYCFLAGS=
MYLDFLAGS=
MYLIBS=
MYOBJS=

# == END OF USER SETTINGS -- NO NEED TO CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE =======

PLATS= aix bsd c89 freebsd generic linux macosx mingw posix solaris

LUA_A=  liblua.a
CORE_O= lapi.o lcode.o lctype.o ldebug.o ldo.o ldump.o lfunc.o lgc.o llex.o \
    lmem.o lobject.o lopcodes.o lparser.o lstate.o lstring.o ltable.o \
    ltm.o lundump.o lvm.o lzio.o
LIB_O= lfs.o crc32.o lauxlib.o lbaselib.o lbitlib.o lcorolib.o ldblib.o liolib.o \
    lmathlib.o loslib.o lstrlib.o ltablib.o lutf8lib.o loadlib.o linit.o 

BASE_O= $(CORE_O) $(LIB_O) $(MYOBJS)

LUA_T=  lua
LUA_O=  lua.o

LUAC_T= luac
LUAC_O= luac.o

ALL_O= $(BASE_O) $(LUA_O) $(LUAC_O)
ALL_T= $(LUA_A) $(LUA_T) $(LUAC_T)
ALL_A= $(LUA_A)

# Targets start here.
default: $(PLAT)

all:    $(ALL_T)

o:  $(ALL_O)

a:  $(ALL_A)

$(LUA_A): $(BASE_O)
    $(AR) $@ $(BASE_O)
    $(RANLIB) $@

$(LUA_T): $(LUA_O) $(LUA_A)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(LUA_O) $(LUA_A) $(LIBS)

$(LUAC_T): $(LUAC_O) $(LUA_A)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(LUAC_O) $(LUA_A) $(LIBS)

clean:
    $(RM) $(ALL_T) $(ALL_O)

depend:
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM l*.c

echo:
    @echo "PLAT= $(PLAT)"
    @echo "CC= $(CC)"
    @echo "CFLAGS= $(CFLAGS)"
    @echo "LDFLAGS= $(SYSLDFLAGS)"
    @echo "LIBS= $(LIBS)"
    @echo "AR= $(AR)"
    @echo "RANLIB= $(RANLIB)"
    @echo "RM= $(RM)"

# Convenience targets for popular platforms
ALL= all

none:
    @echo "Please do 'make PLATFORM' where PLATFORM is one of these:"
    @echo "   $(PLATS)"

aix:
    $(MAKE) $(ALL) CC="xlc" CFLAGS="-O2 -DLUA_USE_POSIX -DLUA_USE_DLOPEN" SYSLIBS="-ldl" SYSLDFLAGS="-brtl -bexpall"

bsd:
    $(MAKE) $(ALL) SYSCFLAGS="-DLUA_USE_POSIX -DLUA_USE_DLOPEN" SYSLIBS="-Wl,-E"

c89:
    $(MAKE) $(ALL) SYSCFLAGS="-DLUA_USE_C89" CC="gcc -std=c89"
    @echo ''
    @echo '*** C89 does not guarantee 64-bit integers for Lua.'
    @echo ''


freebsd:
    $(MAKE) $(ALL) SYSCFLAGS="-DLUA_USE_LINUX" SYSLIBS="-Wl,-E -lreadline"

generic: $(ALL)

linux:
    $(MAKE) $(ALL) SYSCFLAGS="-DLUA_USE_LINUX" SYSLIBS="-Wl,-E -ldl -lreadline"

macosx:
    $(MAKE) $(ALL) SYSCFLAGS="-DLUA_USE_MACOSX" SYSLIBS="-lreadline" CC=cc

mingw:
    $(MAKE) "LUA_A=lua53.dll" "LUA_T=lua.exe" \
    "AR=$(CC) -shared -o" "RANLIB=strip --strip-unneeded" \
    "SYSCFLAGS=-DLUA_BUILD_AS_DLL" "SYSLIBS=" "SYSLDFLAGS=-s" lua.exe
    $(MAKE) "LUAC_T=luac.exe" luac.exe

posix:
    $(MAKE) $(ALL) SYSCFLAGS="-DLUA_USE_POSIX"

solaris:
    $(MAKE) $(ALL) SYSCFLAGS="-DLUA_USE_POSIX -DLUA_USE_DLOPEN -D_REENTRANT" SYSLIBS="-ldl"

# list targets that do not create files (but not all makes understand .PHONY)
.PHONY: all $(PLATS) default o a clean depend echo none

# DO NOT DELETE
lapi.o: lapi.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h lapi.h llimits.h lstate.h \
 lobject.h ltm.h lzio.h lmem.h ldebug.h ldo.h lfunc.h lgc.h lstring.h \
 ltable.h lundump.h lvm.h
lauxlib.o: lauxlib.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h lauxlib.h
lbaselib.o: lbaselib.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h lauxlib.h lualib.h
lbitlib.o: lbitlib.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h lauxlib.h lualib.h
lcode.o: lcode.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h lcode.h llex.h lobject.h \
 llimits.h lzio.h lmem.h lopcodes.h lparser.h ldebug.h lstate.h ltm.h \
 ldo.h lgc.h lstring.h ltable.h lvm.h
lcorolib.o: lcorolib.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h lauxlib.h lualib.h
lctype.o: lctype.c lprefix.h lctype.h lua.h luaconf.h llimits.h
ldblib.o: ldblib.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h lauxlib.h lualib.h
ldebug.o: ldebug.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h lapi.h llimits.h lstate.h \
 lobject.h ltm.h lzio.h lmem.h lcode.h llex.h lopcodes.h lparser.h \
 ldebug.h ldo.h lfunc.h lstring.h lgc.h ltable.h lvm.h
ldo.o: ldo.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h lapi.h llimits.h lstate.h \
 lobject.h ltm.h lzio.h lmem.h ldebug.h ldo.h lfunc.h lgc.h lopcodes.h \
 lparser.h lstring.h ltable.h lundump.h lvm.h
ldump.o: ldump.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h lobject.h llimits.h lstate.h \
 ltm.h lzio.h lmem.h lundump.h
lfunc.o: lfunc.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h lfunc.h lobject.h llimits.h \
 lgc.h lstate.h ltm.h lzio.h lmem.h
lgc.o: lgc.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h ldebug.h lstate.h lobject.h \
 llimits.h ltm.h lzio.h lmem.h ldo.h lfunc.h lgc.h lstring.h ltable.h
linit.o: linit.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h lualib.h lauxlib.h
liolib.o: liolib.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h lauxlib.h lualib.h
llex.o: llex.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h lctype.h llimits.h ldebug.h \
 lstate.h lobject.h ltm.h lzio.h lmem.h ldo.h lgc.h llex.h lparser.h \
 lstring.h ltable.h
lmathlib.o: lmathlib.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h lauxlib.h lualib.h
lmem.o: lmem.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h ldebug.h lstate.h lobject.h \
 llimits.h ltm.h lzio.h lmem.h ldo.h lgc.h
loadlib.o: loadlib.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h lauxlib.h lualib.h
lobject.o: lobject.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h lctype.h llimits.h \
 ldebug.h lstate.h lobject.h ltm.h lzio.h lmem.h ldo.h lstring.h lgc.h \
 lvm.h
lopcodes.o: lopcodes.c lprefix.h lopcodes.h llimits.h lua.h luaconf.h
loslib.o: loslib.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h lauxlib.h lualib.h
lparser.o: lparser.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h lcode.h llex.h lobject.h \
 llimits.h lzio.h lmem.h lopcodes.h lparser.h ldebug.h lstate.h ltm.h \
 ldo.h lfunc.h lstring.h lgc.h ltable.h
lstate.o: lstate.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h lapi.h llimits.h lstate.h \
 lobject.h ltm.h lzio.h lmem.h ldebug.h ldo.h lfunc.h lgc.h llex.h \
 lstring.h ltable.h
lstring.o: lstring.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h ldebug.h lstate.h \
 lobject.h llimits.h ltm.h lzio.h lmem.h ldo.h lstring.h lgc.h
lstrlib.o: lstrlib.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h lauxlib.h lualib.h
ltable.o: ltable.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h ldebug.h lstate.h lobject.h \
 llimits.h ltm.h lzio.h lmem.h ldo.h lgc.h lstring.h ltable.h lvm.h
ltablib.o: ltablib.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h lauxlib.h lualib.h
ltm.o: ltm.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h ldebug.h lstate.h lobject.h \
 llimits.h ltm.h lzio.h lmem.h ldo.h lstring.h lgc.h ltable.h lvm.h
lua.o: lua.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h lauxlib.h lualib.h
luac.o: luac.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h lauxlib.h lobject.h llimits.h \
 lstate.h ltm.h lzio.h lmem.h lundump.h ldebug.h lopcodes.h
lundump.o: lundump.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h ldebug.h lstate.h \
 lobject.h llimits.h ltm.h lzio.h lmem.h ldo.h lfunc.h lstring.h lgc.h \
 lundump.h
lutf8lib.o: lutf8lib.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h lauxlib.h lualib.h
lvm.o: lvm.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h ldebug.h lstate.h lobject.h \
 llimits.h ltm.h lzio.h lmem.h ldo.h lfunc.h lgc.h lopcodes.h lstring.h \
 ltable.h lvm.h
lzio.o: lzio.c lprefix.h lua.h luaconf.h llimits.h lmem.h lstate.h \
 lobject.h ltm.h lzio.h
lfs.o: lfs.c lfs.h
crc32.o: crc32.c crc32.h

# (end of Makefile)
```

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Have you added lfs in linit.c?

Comment: @lhf thanks a lot, it is the point. but I didn't see this code in Linit.c in my old lua 5.1 project, it's weird...

Answer (score 2):

This is what I have done and it works well:

linit.c

Added LFS in this section:

```
static const luaL_Reg loadedlibs[] = {
  {"_G", luaopen_base},
   ...
  {LUA_LFSLIBNAME, luaopen_lfs},
```

and in lualib.h added

```
#define LUA_LFSLIBNAME  "lfs"
LUAMOD_API int (luaopen_lfs) (lua_State *L);
```

Then build as usual.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need add `lfs` to `linit.c` and rebuild.